# Right click browse with have more than one browser?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I seem to remember with VS 2012 when I right clicked on a web project I had the ability to choose from multiple browsers. This might have been added through an extension though.

With 2015 there is now a button in the toolbar which lets you pick from different browsers, there are two problems with this.

1. Clicking this button starts a debug session which I don't need to do 95% of the time.
2. If I want to use a different browser to test something, I need to select it from this toolbar dropdown then right click on the project and run it.

Is there an extension or some other way to add a list of all defined browsers to the menu when I right click on a web project?